# How to compare 2 c++ dll files

Tags: c++

I have a problem about comparing 2 dll files which are generated when I build my solution.

My programming language of dll files is C++

***Scenario:**
I have a tool which help me to build some VisualStudio solution.
Before, This tool used devenv.exe to build solution.
Now, I must to use MSBuild.exe to build solution.
However, I need to confirm that the generated dll files are the same between built by Devenv.exe and by MSBuild.exe.

***My solution:**
I try to use Dumpbin in VisualStuio command prompt.
I checked RAWDATA of result (which are generated by Dumpbin from my dll files).

But there're some differences.

I tried to use RAWDATA dumpin for 2 dll files which are built by devenv.exe. But it's still different.

Besides, RAWDATA is hex-data, I cannot know what the differences means?.

Can someone help me to compare 2 dll files which are built from devenv.exe and msbuild.exe?
(I think it's the same, but we need the evidence for my customer)

Comment: Could you just read both files in a c++ script and compare by bytes?

Comment: Even if the two executables used the same compiler internally, there is never a guarantee that two compilations of the same code in the same compiler will be completely equal.  So I have a feeling this whole exercise is moot.  Do the compilations as needed, and just make sure the two DLL versions *function* properly at runtime as expected.  Don't try to compare the raw DLL data.

Comment: Thanks for all your answer.
"equals" means compare by bytes.

Comment: @ChrisHappy, Could you explain more detail for me?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I got it, but my requirement is providing the evidence of 2 c++ file if it is the same.